# Convert messageBox in asp.net in VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following function that creates a message box.

```
Function Question() As Boolean

    If MsgBox("Are you sure?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Question") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
         RunSubRoutine()
         txtbox.focus                   
         Return True
     Else
         Return False
    End If

End Function
```

How would I change it so it works the same in ASP.Net because I need it to return a value?

Comment: you mean display an alert in asp.net?

Comment: Well a confirmation box.

Comment: see my post, it is a javascript. You need to attach it to the page. hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can't prompt the user that way because ASP.NET is server-side language. You need to use javascript (or JQuery for more advanced popup windows) to do that like this:

```
<script>
    function Question() {
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            document.getElementById("your_textbox_id").focus()
        }
    }
</script>
```

**And if you want the confirmation to return back to the server:**

There are a lot ways to do it depending on your requirements.
I cannot know which will fit best in your stiation but the eaisest way to refresh the page by adding a query string value to the main url. For example, let's say your URL is www.blabla.com/test.aspx then you can just redirect the client browser like this:

```
<script>
    function Question() {
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            window.location.href = "test.aspx?confirm=yes";
        }
    }
</script>
```

and then catch the querystring in the test.aspx page by using:

```
If Request.QueryString("confirm") = "yes" then
     //call your asp.net routine here
End If
```

Or you can POST the result returned from javascript to the server by making an AJAX request, which is more complicated but doesn't need to reload the page...

Comment: What should I do if I wanted to call another sub routine in the statement?

Answer (score 0):

**There is no such direct option to achieve this.**

ASP.NET distroy the process after page loading. You can send request either using ajax or event handling.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as messagebox in asp.net. You can do this alternative.

```
if(confirm('Are you sure?')){
   // do this
}
else{
   // do something else
}
```